# Identify groups that have an A-B-A change

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have to find occurrences in the data that match a change like 'A-B-A'. I have my dataset grouped and sorted in the correct way. The values that need to be compared are the columns VAL1 and VAL2. In this example they are numbers, but they might be string values as well.

#### Sample Data explanation

All values of VAL1 and VAL2 in group **1** are different and I'm not interested in these A-B-C changes.

All values of VAL1 and VAL2 in group **2** are the same, which is fine too. Changes like A-A-A or even A-A-B-B-B-C are fine and I'm not interested in those either.

In group **3** the first and the third VAL1 and VAL2 are the same. So this is the kind of A-B-A change I'm looking for. Also changes like

- A-B-C-B
- A-B-C-D-A

I am interested in. Basically it does not matter where in the group the previous same row is, as long as there is a different row in between I'm interested in this Group

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
     [273,1,'01.01.2016','16.02.2017','23154','1'],
     [273,1,'16.03.2017','31.10.2019','48625','1'],
     [273,1,'01.11.2019','31.12.2099','32007','1'],
     [274,2,'01.01.2016','16.02.2017','23154','1'],
     [274,2,'16.03.2017','31.10.2019','23154','1'],
     [275,3,'01.01.2016','16.02.2017','78945','1'],
     [275,3,'16.03.2017','31.10.2019','48625','2'],
     [275,3,'01.11.2019','31.12.2099','78945','1'],
 ], columns=['ID','GROUP','FROM','UNTIL','VAL1','VAL2'])
```

#### What I want

I would like the resulting dataframe to only have the groups which do have a kind of A-B-A change in them.

So in my example data only the rows of group **3** would remain.

#### My attempt at the problem

My Idea is to first find any duplicates for each group, then check in the group with duplicates if there are any A-B-A changes and last only select the groups that fullfill the criteria.

So I ran the pandas duplicate function like this

```
df['DUPES'] = df.duplicated(subset=['GROUP', 'VAL1', 'VAL2'], keep=False)
```

and got following dataframe, but I do not know how to progress from this point on.

|  | ID | Group | From | Until | Val1 | Val2 | Dupes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 273 | 1 | 01.01.2016 | 16.02.2017 | 23154 | 1 | False |
| 1 | 273 | 1 | 16.03.2017 | 31.10.2019 | 48625 | 1 | False |
| 2 | 273 | 1 | 01.11.2019 | 31.12.2099 | 32007 | 1 | False |
| 3 | 274 | 2 | 01.01.2016 | 16.02.2017 | 23154 | 1 | True |
| 4 | 274 | 2 | 16.03.2017 | 31.10.2019 | 23154 | 1 | True |
| 5 | 275 | 3 | 01.01.2016 | 16.02.2017 | 78945 | 1 | True |
| 6 | 275 | 3 | 16.03.2017 | 31.10.2019 | 48625 | 2 | False |
| 7 | 275 | 3 | 01.11.2019 | 31.12.2099 | 78945 | 1 | True |

Next I would need to check if there are are A-B-A changes in a group I'd like to find. So my Idea is to check each member in the group

- If it is the first item in the group and it is a Dupe it should be ignored
- If it is NOT the first but a Dupe AND

  - the previous entry in the group has the same Val1 and Val2 it is a valid A-A change
  - the previous entry in the group has NOT the same Val1 and Val2 found an A-B-A change

I know I can use a mask like `df['VAL1'].eq(df['VAL1'].shift()) & df['VAL2'].eq(df['VAL2'].shift())` to compare with the previous value, but how would I limit this to the group? Also I'm not checking if the value is ...

Edit: I played around a little more and came up with this mask

```
df['DUPES2'] = df['DUPES'] & df['GROUP'].eq(df['GROUP'].shift()) & ~(df['VAL1'].eq(df['VAL1'].shift()) & df['VAL2'].eq(df['VAL2'].shift()))
```

The resulting dataframe looks fine, but I still do not know how to only select the groups

|  | ID | Group | From | Until | Val1 | Val2 | Dupe2 | Dupes2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 273 | 1 | 01.01.2016 | 16.02.2017 | 23154 | 1 | False | False |
| 1 | 273 | 1 | 16.03.2017 | 31.10.2019 | 48625 | 1 | False | False |
| 2 | 273 | 1 | 01.11.2019 | 31.12.2099 | 32007 | 1 | False | False |
| 3 | 274 | 2 | 01.01.2016 | 16.02.2017 | 23154 | 1 | True | False |
| 4 | 274 | 2 | 16.03.2017 | 31.10.2019 | 23154 | 1 | True | False |
| 5 | 275 | 3 | 01.01.2016 | 16.02.2017 | 78945 | 1 | True | False |
| 6 | 275 | 3 | 16.03.2017 | 31.10.2019 | 48625 | 2 | False | False |
| 7 | 275 | 3 | 01.11.2019 | 31.12.2099 | 78945 | 1 | True | True |

#### Question to the community

Is there any other way how I could utilize pandas functionality to achieve my goal?

Thanks for helping

Comment: first youcould use `groupby` to work with every groups separatelly, next you could use `shift()` two times to have 3 values in one row and compare them. OR you could use `rolling window` (with size 3) to work with 3 rows at the same time.

Comment: Since I'm fairly new to the pandas syntax could you outline @furas how the `groupby` would look like?

Comment: The rolling window does not seem to be the correct thing to do, since there could be any number of rows between the duplicate rows. What I changed though, since I posted my question was to remove `keep=False` from the duplicate function which does not mark the first occurence as duplicate and the result is better.